# Is there a way to access the man pages on my Mac 10.13.6 in a machine-readable format like JSON?

Tags: terminal, command-line

Is there a way to access the man pages on my Mac 10.13.6 in a machine-readable format like JSON?

Someone like https://qr.ae/prxY74 recommended installing and using `mandoc`, but unlike what he mentioned in the link provided, `mandoc -Tjson` is not a valid flag, as documented on https://mandoc.bsd.lv/man/mandoc.1.html..

Is there any other way?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Arguably, man files are machine readable, as they are text with formatting characters.

Comment: `/usr/share/man/man1/bash.1` is actually already machine-readable, it just comes from time where machine-readable meant something else :-)

Comment: The actual originbal files are a text format - they are not designed to fit into JSON. The nearest is if you could find man pages in SGML rather than troff.

Comment: I am trying to use PHP to take the man pages as input, and extract each line describing the options and flags for a command as output, for a learning program I am building. It does not seem easy to parse the troff man pages with PHP, but far easier with JSON.

Comment: @mmmmmm may I know how the man pages can be extracted in SGML?

Comment: actually if I can achieve what I need to achieve with the `troff` command, that's also possible.. is it possible with `troff`?

Comment: The troff pages are the original - they have not been written in a form that allows any more complex semantic parsing of the text. You'll have to look at the troff markup to see if it is enough.

Comment: Troff uses a markup language, so you can't easily derive the semantic structure from the source files. And even Google isn't aware of a `mandoc-json` package/script/whatever so whatever the person on Quora referred to is either gone or has never existed.